# How do you access a UiPath StudioX activity from Studio?

Tags: uipath, uipath-studio, uipath-robot

I’m working with UiPath Studio but need the features of an activity I used with StudioX.

How do you access StudioX activities from Studio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a funnel icon on the Activities tab in UiPath Studio for Developers. Click on it and one of the options is "Show StudioX."

[image]

If you click this "Show StudioX" button, UiPath [StudioX activities](https://youtu.be/sMaLZFY7ys4) become available to the full blow Studio product.